# syntax error on token "-", -- expected

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Kepler Service Release 2, with jdk1.8.0 installed as the JRE.

I am using *Java All-in-one For Dummies* to learn Java SE 8, and, when writing a program, using Swing, I am getting this error: `syntax error on token "-", -- expected`

With this code:

```
button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
button1.addActionListener(e -> button1Click() );
panel1.add(button1);

exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
exitButton.addActionListener(e -> exitButtonClick() );
panel1.add(exitButton);
this.add(panel1);
```

button1 and exitButton have been declared as JButtons already, and I have imported javax.swing.* and java.awt.event.*.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's `e`? What is it?

Comment: Is Java 8 set as the target (err, "source") language?

Comment: Incidentally, you can use method references. Make sure your `button1Click` (for example) method takes an `ActionEvent` then just pass `MyClass::button1Click` to the method.

Comment: @AnubianNoob `e` is part of the syntax of lambdas in Java 8.  In this case, the lambda means we're creating an `ActionListener` whose `actionPerformed` method takes an `ActionEvent` parameter named `e` and then performs the expression on the right of `->`.  That expression could refer to `e` as the parameter, but event listeners often don't need to use their parameter.  See [this tutorial on lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you are on kepler install this update : http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

and then set

```
windows > preferences > java > compiler > compiler compliance level > 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here, since I got here from Google and fixed my own error later on: the `Syntax error on token "-", -- expected` error is also raised when, instead of using `->` in a lambda expression, you use `- >` (that is, with a space in between the two characters, in which case Java suspects that you're trying to use `--`).